# How can i diplay all my CSV data in table?

Tags: php, csv

I upload csv file and verify the extension. After the file is uploaded, I want to display all data of the CSV file in HTML table.

My problem is that it displays anything and when i use var_dump this is the result :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "bm borj    20" [1]=> NULL }
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "sm  sam 25" [1]=> NULL }
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "ad  med 30" [1]=> NULL }
```

PHP :

```
            <?php
                            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                            error_reporting(E_ALL);
                            $sel_file = array();
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                $result = array(); 
                                $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
                                $ext = explode(".", $fname);
                                if (strtolower(end($ext)) == "csv") {
                                    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
                                    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
                                    fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");
                                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                                    {

                                        $result[]=$data;

                                    }

                                    var_dump($result);
                                    fclose($handle);
                                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable text-center'>
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Successfully Imported
                                    </div>";

                                } 

                                else 
                                {
                                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-center'>
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Successfully Imported
                                    </div>";
                                }
                            /*  var_dump($result);*/
                                ?>

                                <form action="/module/getCSV.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Export as CSV" onclick="getCSVData()" class="btn btn-success">
                                </form>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="panel">
                                    <div class="panel-body">    
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display" id="table_with_sorting" style="zoom: 85%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>


                                                <?php
                                                          foreach($result as $a => $p)              
                                                ?>
                                                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><? echo $p['']; ?></td>



                                                    </tr>
                                                <?php 
                                                endforeach; 

                                                ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
```

This my CSV File :

[image]

Comment: A couple of things jump out: 1) the WHILE loop gets terminated by the die() and 2) $row is always 0.

Comment: @BigScar even if I delete it it changes nothing.

Comment: You never update $row inside the loop, so you keep just setting `$sel_file[0]` over and over...

Comment: So what what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the example in the manual: [PHP: fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.fgetcsv.php)

```
<?php
$result=array(); // put the data from CSV here

$filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $result[]=$data;

    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Your script has some problems here:

- You use ";" instead of "," as separator
- $row has no use in your script

Check here in YOUR script:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
```

Hope this helps!

It will return:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "lastname" [1]=> string(9) "firstname" [2]=> string(3) "age" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "bm" [1]=> string(4) "borj" [2]=> string(2) "20" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "sm" [1]=> string(3) "sam" [2]=> string(2) "25" } [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "ad" [1]=> string(3) "med" [2]=> string(2) "30" } }
```

P.s. Remember that with fgetcsv:

> A blank line in a CSV file will be returned as an array comprising a
>   single null field, and will not be treated as an error.

EDIT:
To get a HTML table instead of an array, use:

```
$filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $result[]=$data;
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>",$data)."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    fclose($handle);
}

//var_dump($result);
?>
```

EDIT2: To put data in Bootstrap Table at the bottom

Change "thead" section to:

```
<?php
echo "<thead><tr>";
foreach ($result[0] as $th) {
    echo "<th style=\"width:10%\">$th</th>";
} unset($th);
echo "</tr></thead>";
?>
```

Change "tbody" section to:

```
<?php
echo "<tbody>";
for ($i=1; $i<count($result); $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>",$result[$i])."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
?>
```

Comment: Now when i use var_dump before handle or after it give me the data without var_dump it return nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what is the final result you want. Do you want a HTML table? Do you want an array? (my example gives you an array) Do you want a simple print of the data? Check the example in the manual.

Comment: Yeah i  used  what ur writed for me, it works just with var_dump.

Comment: I want a HTML table with all data of my csv file.

Comment: Ok, check the last part of the answer.

Comment: Yeah i check it, i update my code in my question how can i use diplay it with my code?

Comment: Look at the last lines of my answer (i changed it): did you see the "echo" and the html tags? Look again.

Comment: The data from CSV is not saved in the $data! It is saved in the $results. So use $results in the "foreach". Plus, what is "$my_data" and "$p" in your question? I give up...

Comment: Thank u so much. I already used that before i wont to use table in while because it displays a table before  the button submit you can look to my code and u will understand. My table is in the bottom of my code i don't know how i can return values with my bootstrap table.

Comment: Okey, Thanks for ur answers verjas :)

Comment: That's it, I made the last change. Hope it works. Good luck!

Comment: No, I changed my answer - last part.

Comment: Maybe you can click this as you answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

My Csv file contained three columns username,email and phone number:

```
$handle = fopen("yourexcel.csv",'r');
if(!$handle) die('Cannot open uploaded file.');

//Read the file as csv
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $username = $data['0'];
    $email = $data['1'];
    $phonenumber = $data['2'];

//here data[0],data[1] are the columns of the excel sheet, if you want so database it then follow  :

    if(strlen($username ) || strlen($email) || strlen($phonenumber)){

    $query2 = "insert into user_master(username,email,phonenumber) values   ('".$username."','".$email."','".$phonenumber."');";
    mysql_query($query2);
    }
```

If you want to just print it "echo" the $data

Comment: I do not want to give it the names of columns I want that recovered all the data in a table on php.

Comment: It returns all my data when i use var_dump but it dosen't display it this is my problem.

Comment: Inside your code, why you have given  $data[1] = null; ? And also, your output displays array2 -> filename array : are you posting file name from any other pages?

Comment: $sel_file  is array , then use **print_r($sel_file);** to display it

Comment: @ I don't use it for other pages.

Comment: when i use print it display Array ( [0] => )

Answer (score -1):

Use the "fread($f, filesize(filename.kit)" instead of fgetcsv.

```
<?Php 
echo "<html><body><table border=1>";
$f = fopen("data2.csv", "r");
$fr = fread($f, filesize("data2.csv"));
fclose($f);
$lines = array();
$lines = explode("\n\r",$fr); // IMPORTANT the delimiter here just the "new line" \r\n, use what u need instead of... 

for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $cells = array(); 
    $cells = explode(";",$lines[$i]); // use the cell/row delimiter what u need!
    for($k=0;$k<count($cells);$k++)
    {
       echo "<td>".$cells[$k]."</td>";
    }
    // for k end
    echo "</tr>";
}
// for i end
echo "</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: First i upload the file, i don't give it a specifiv CSV file to read it and when i use fread, it gives errors.

Comment: you realize that fgetcsv is already basically doing `fread()` followed by `explode()` **ANYWAYS**. it's a csv. why advocate NOT using the tool specifically DESIGNED to read those files?